# Is there any design pattern available for pushing data from devices to cloud?

Tags: design, design-patterns

Hopefully I am posting a question in right forum. As per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering-se-previo `software engineering' seems to be the right choice for my question.

**So question is,**

We are in `IoT` era, and most of new bee's like me having the challenges to choose the right architecture or design implementation for securely send messages from device to any cloud without any data loss.

So based on my analysis, I have started with `MQTT` and below is high level design

[image]

**Design of Gateway**

[image]

Good news is it works, and send data to cloud. But I am not able figure out how to trace the messages which are successfully sent to cloud or not! How do I make sure message delivery is success. Do I need to have internal small SQL lite DB to store the messages and mark it as success if it delivered to the cloud?

Secondly, Is it secure design? What happens device landed in to wrong hands, will he/she start flooding my cloud data center? I am planning to use `certificates` but does it solve the needs?

I am using MQTTnet from https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet

Comment: down vote? It's so strange that people don't help but down vote it so that no one can help :(  Everyone on this earth is not smart geeks. So please appreciate the questions. IoT is new and standard design must be available. I have spent time for drawing so that it's easy for readers to understand. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand either: I upvoted already. I find this question well written; perhaps it is a bit broad in scope. But that is more a reason to close than to downvote.

Comment: Pointless downvoting new questions with no evident reason seems to becoming  endemic and is always the same people that do it.  Shakes head.

Comment: If you haven’t yet, take a look at AWS IOT service, even if you don’t want to use it directly it may give you some ideas about how these things are implemented and how the clients are secured.

Comment: At a guess, any question with "design pattern" in the title gets downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make sure message delivery is success

It depends on your usecase:

- Is it necessary to queue things up in case of transmission errors?
- Does perhaps a simple retry-logic do the trick?
- Is it sufficient to have your consuming services to know that there is no current data / data missing in the timeline

I suppose the question is answered differently depending on whether you have to deal with home automation or maybe cool chains.

> Do I need to have internal small SQL lite DB to store the messages and mark it as success if it delivered to the cloud?

I am not familiar with `MQTT` in detail, but I suppose it features `pop`ing and `pushing` messages. So your consuming service on the backend pops a message off the broker's queue and in case of any transmission / processing errors, it could push it back. The `broker` should handle the persistence of its messages itself. This means: the existence of a message in the queue indicates its *unprocessed* status.

---

Disclaimer: I am no security expert, so the following is to be read *cum grano salis*.

> Secondly, Is it secure design?

Depending on your definition of security *yes* or *no*. What are the security risks you want to mitigate? E.g. Not sending data easily readable by everyone, TLS will help.

> What happens device landed in to wrong hands, will he/she start flooding my cloud data center? I am planning to use certificates but does it solve the needs?

Certificates are a second factor in a `2FA` system. You have one thing you "know" - like `username` and `password`; and another thing you *have*, which is the certificate.

Say one steals your credentials, but not having your certificate, the credentials are worthless.

Regarding your scenario of *stealing* a device:

**a)** the one *having* the device, *has* also the certificate

**b)** I suppose when it is in general possible to reverse engineer `username` and `password`, it should also be possible to extract the certificate.

If you want to mitigate *unauthorized* devices, this is hardly possible.

If you want to mitigate *false* data, this is also hardly possible.

If you want to mitigate only "flooding your datacenter", you have to establish some kind of "firewall"-system allowing a limited number of messages in a given timeframe - meaning a packetfilter as well as some throttling / "fraud"-detection / validation on the application level.

For more in depth analysis / help I recommend opening a new thread over at [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Basically I am writing a gateway service and installing on the devices. devices will publish messages to the gateway and it will send to cloud. I am sure how do this design when considering the scaling!

Comment: As for I said, I have not worked with MQTT, so I do not know, how to do this right. But I suppose, that the role of the "broker" as I understand it after skimming Wikipedia is more of a backend one, rather than on the device itself. So your gateway should be part of something between device and backend: Device->Broker->Backend(including cloud storage)

Answer (score 2):

A few things which throw red flags for me:

1. *Don't* let your program directly upload to the cloud.  It should upload to your backend server, and your backend server uploads to the cloud if anything.  Otherwise yes, the user could potentially have full control over all cloud resources.
2. Accept the possibility of failure.  Put yourself in a position that when failure occurs, you know exactly *where* it failed and how to fix it.  For instance, if your message state is "PENDING", the very moment you establish a connection with the server before the actual upload, switch state to "SENDING" so that should something go awry, you know you were uploading at the moment of failure.
3. You absolutely must have a means to know that the upload has finished, without which your program can never know that a file has been uploaded.  If no means is provided, you must find a means.  An e-mail server which isn't given a response from the destination mail server that an e-mail has been delivered successfully is never going to be able to know if the e-mail was sent, *even if it was!*

Comment: @ThomasJunk All credentials necessary to access the cloud encrypted or otherwise must be present client-side before you can access the cloud.  A little bit of reverse engineering will give you full control over all cloud resources, which may also include other client data...  Not a smart move.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Supposing you could get around this somehow, you still have 0 control over how many resources can be uploaded to the cloud under your account.  They can fill it up if they wished.  The cloud would have to have some sort of support for such a thing before it would be viable.

Comment: I should have made the smiley more visible. Deleted original comment.

Comment: so load will be more on backend server? then I might need to have load balancers right?

Comment: @codetoshare Load balancers issue is unrelated.  You should certainly be able to handle multiple connections on the backend though.

Comment: Interesting thoughts. However, it all depends on the use cases. Many IoT devices upload directly to the cloud because it eases deployment (i.e. all you need is an internet connection). Some use cases even can afford some losses of data. But in general I agree with your points. Uploading directly to the cloud might create a dependencies and bottlenecks, and overconsume bandwith without necessity. These are the arguments in favor of the **[fog architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_computing)** vs the cloud